# Build dynamic checkboxes

Tags: jstl

Hey guys I have about 8 fieldSets  and Im iterating over a list. I want to fill up the checkboxes based off a value of each iteration for ex.

```
 <c:if test="${detBean.groupName == 'HEADER_DATA}">
```

*Add that checkbox to that fieldset and so on...

```
    <c:forEach var="detBean" items="${detFields}">
    Display Name -- ${detBean.displayName}
    Field Name -- ${detBean.fieldName} 
    Group Name -- ${detBean.groupName}
    </c:forEach>

<tr>
        <td>
            <div id="displayFields" style="display:block;">
            <fieldset class="det">

                <legend>Header Data</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="${detBean.displayName}
" value="${detBean.displayName}
">${detBean.displayName}
</input>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="det">
                <legend>Materiel Data</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="${detBean.displayName}
" value="${detBean.displayName}
">${detBean.displayName}
</input>
            <br/>

        </fieldset>
      </td>
        </tr>
```

Thankx

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question? Your EL example "When (${detBean.groupName} == "HEADER_DATA")" is by the way invalid. Not sure if this is a red herring or not.

Comment: thats psuedo code...Basically while it's iterating if we reached an istance of the bean that matches the condition check make a check box here

Comment: Yes OK. What's your question/problem then? The title is extremely broad and the code posted so far doesn't contain obvious syntax errors (although indentation is odd), so I don't see any clear question/problem.

Comment: Should i use <c:when> or <c:if>?

Comment: Why exactly are you asking that? What exactly is the problem you have with for example `<c:if>`?

Comment: I still don't understand your concrete problem.

Comment: I was not sure how to construt it.  I tried using <c:when> and it didnt work.

Comment: In the future try to ask a concrete programming question about a concrete problem instead of an overly broad and localized "question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
 <div id="displayFields" style="display:block;">
            <fieldset class="det">
                <legend>Header Data</legend>
                <c:forEach var="detBean" items="${detFields}">
                <c:if test="${detBean.groupName == 'HEADER_DATA'}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="${detBean.displayName}" value="${detBean.displayName}">${detBean.displayName}</input>
            <br/>
                </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="det">
                <legend>Materiel Data</legend>
                <c:forEach var="detBean" items="${detFields}">
                <c:if test="${detBean.groupName == 'MATERIEL_DATA'}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="${detBean.displayName}" value="${detBean.displayName}">${detBean.displayName}</input>
            <br/>
                </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
        </fieldset>
```